# Is it possible to use $size with a condition?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use the $size operator when sub-docs meet a specific condition?

Here is the example doc:

```
{
   likes: [{
     like: true,
     username: 'bob'
   }, {
     like: false,
     username: 'tim'
   }]
   ..... other attributes
}
```

Is it possible to query the docs and $set a count for the likes where like is true?

```
'$set': {
  'likeCount': {
    $size: '$likes',
  },
},
```

The above will return `likeCount` as 2 from the example doc

But what i would like to do is return a count of the docs where like is true, ie:

```
'$set': {
  'likeCount': {
    $size: {
      '$likes': {
        like: true
      }
    },
  },
},
```

But i just get an error:

```
MongoError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$likes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lE2UKKG5qXv)

Query

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "true-like-count": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$likes",
            "cond": "$$this.like"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` in a `$project` stage like this to have only values where your condition is match:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "likes": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$likes",
          "as": "l",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$l.like",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "likeCount": {
        $size: "$likes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NO3dpKbl1pG)

Also if you don't want to loose the array `likes` you can create an auxiliar value like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KatwHK9NSCw)

Comment: Is it possible to use a $filter cond to match fields that exist?  eg a date field:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/rambIiK-UgS

Comment: I only get invalid $set :/

Comment: Maybe [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ut_2WnOuxAg) helps you? I can add into answer if you want.

Comment: we have [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) also,  in your case you could do it also like `{"$ne" : [ {"$type" : "$$l.t"}, "missing" ]}`  , undefined looks faster but i dont know how to use it in java so i use this.